# need Adblockplus filter systemwide via /etc/hosts

Tags: python, linux, selenium, adblock, hosts-file

I'm scraping some websites to get at content they have using `selenium` in python. I can run headless `firefox` via `geckodriver` with `marionette` capability set to `True` with `adblockplus` extension enabled and it works well. However recent versions of `firefox` (as of March 2021) don't support performance logging - which is a must for my purpose. So I've had to switch to using `chromedriver` and Chromium. Logging works great but chromium when being run in headless mode has no support for browser extensions and throws errors.

So I figure I keep using `chromedriver` with Chromium but not having `adblockplus` or any other adblocking is really hurting my runtime and there are some overlays that wouldn't be there otherwise.

How can I find and extract the filter list of my `adblockplus` browser extension so I can apply the same filtering by using the domain names in there and my `/etc/hosts` file i.e. sending all those 'bad' domains to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

If you open the settings and click on the advanced. you will see the filters. Each filter points to an url where there are stored.

[image]

1.The easy list i previous linked: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt
2. The ABP filters https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/abp-filters-anti-cv.txt

Comment: I expected the format won't be plain text, I'm prepared to write a script for that purpose - I just need to know how the info is stored inside `adblockplus` since they are very motivated to always have a comprehensive list and routinely strive towards that goal. Thanks for the lists but I've already come across them - they're good but only a subset of what I could get from `adblockplus` - at best

Comment: Well there are two of them. I've updated the response

Comment: tnx @art_architect